# GNOME Tweak Tool's numpad delete key behaviour doesn't work

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout, gnome-tweak-tool, xkb

I use a lot of keyboard layouts, but some of them have comma instead of dot on the numpad delete key. I want to override this behaviour and always use dot, but when I open gnome-tweak-tool, then go to "Typing" and set "Numeric keypad delete key behaviour" to "Legacy key with dot" or any other option, it just doesn't work. I have tried restarting GNOME Shell or rebooting the computer, but nothing seems to work. That setting has worked before I upgraded Ubuntu from 14.10 to 15.04, but now it just stopped working.

Also when I start GNOME Shell, it always use English keyboard layout as default, I can change it, but it starts with English. That's kinda weird, because before upgrade it was last used layout, not always English, so I think that may be related.

I use Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 with GNOME Shell 3.14.4.
Some additional info from terminal:

```
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,szl,pl,us
variant:    ,,,
options:    nbsp:level2,keypad:oss,kpdl:dot
```

Note: It doesn't list all my keyboard layouts, I'm not sure if it's a bug or a feature.